# Writing a windows class driver

Tags: windows, driver, cdc

I'm new to WDM driver development, but I have an experience developing
Linux drivers.

i want to develop Ethernet over USB class driver for windows XP. (CDC-ECM class driver)

i know that windows only support RNDIS/NDIS for the network class and thus i will need to write a custom windows driver that replace the RNDIS driver while maintaining the rest of the USB stack.

so far i downloaded the windows driver kit (WDK) and still reading the documentation.

does anyone know how to do this or where to get started ? (other than WDK documentation)

i tried google but still can't figure it out.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a [NDIS Miniport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) driver which uses a USB KMDF miniport driver at the lower edge.

Comment: thanks, is there a sample or article that explains this approach more ? (other than the msdn poorly documented page)

Comment: This is a sample from the WDK for minport NDIS drivers : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570734(v=vs.85).aspx